Why do different integration approaches involving Dirac delta function lead to a result differing by a factor of two?
I am considering a problem where the length distribution of segments is given by $P(\ell)$, and I want to calculate the probability that "the sum of two adjacent segment lengths is $2\ell$". I have come up with two integration approaches:

Let $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ be the lengths of two adjacent segments. We can write
$$
P_{\mathrm{sum}}(\ell) = \iint P(\ell_1)P(\ell_2) \delta\left(\ell - \frac {\ell_1+\ell_2}{2}\right)\,\mathrm d\ell_1\,\mathrm d\ell_2
$$

If the first one is $\ell_11$ then the second one must be $\ell_2$, such that we have
$$
P_{\mathrm{sum}} = \int P(\ell_1) P(2\ell-\ell_1)\,\mathrm d\ell_1
$$
we can see this integration gives a result that is half of what I get from the first method.


I know the first approach is correct. But, where did I go wrong with the second one?

Your formula are be equal (you are integrating over $l$2$ not $l$).  However they will only work if the lengths for adjacent segments are independent and identically distributed.  If not, then you should be integrating the joint probability density function.

@GrahamKemp In my problem, we think the lengths of two segments are independent and identically distribution. But why are my formula equal? For the first approach, we have $\delta(l-(l_1+l_2)/2)=2 \delta(l_2-(2l-l_1))$. The second one is half of the first one.

Place and scale the Dirac delta function appropriately to a unit impulse spike on the axis of the variable of integration.  $$\iint_{\Bbb R^2} P(l_1),P(l_2),\boldsymbol\delta(l_2-(2l-l_1)),\mathrm d l_2,\mathrm dl_1 = \int_\Bbb R P(l_1),P(2l-l_1),\mathrm d l_1$$

Are you accounting for the Composition with a function property of the Dirac delta function?
